# Delete Node if Child is empty with php?

Tags: php, xml

I want to be able to to delete a node tree if a specific child is empty, but seems to do something wrong?

Here is what I got:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <game id="1">
    <opponent>Michael</opponent>
    <oppid>1</oppid>
  </game>
  <game id="2">
    <opponent>Trish</opponent>
    <oppid>55</oppid>
  </game>
  <game id="3">
    <opponent/>
    <oppid>24</oppid>
  </game>
  <game id="4">
    <opponent>Betty</opponent>
    <oppid>12</oppid>
  </game>
</data>

');

echo "<xmp>OLD \n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

$xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);
foreach($xpath->query('//game') as $node) {
    if($node->opponent == ''){
        echo 'Test<br>';
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }

}

echo "<xmp>NEW \n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
```

I get 4 "Test" printed out and in the NEW xmp I get nothing? What am I doing wrong?

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: "but seems to do something wrong?" Yeah, but how should WE know whats wrong ion your eyes… `$node->opponent` looks like SImpleXML but you are using DOMDocument.

Comment: He, thats right ;-) So how should I continue using DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
<game id="1">
    <opponent>Michael</opponent>
    <oppid>1</oppid>
</game>
<game id="2">
    <opponent>Trish</opponent>
    <oppid>55</oppid>
</game>
<game id="3">
    <opponent/>
    <oppid>24</oppid>
</game>
<game id="4">
    <opponent>Betty</opponent>
    <oppid>12</oppid>
</game>
</data>

');

echo "<xmp>OLD \n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

$opNodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('opponent');
foreach($opNodes as $node) {
    $innerHtml = trim($node->nodeValue);
    if(empty($innerHtml)){
        $gameNode = $node->parentNode;
        $gameNode->parentNode->removeChild($gameNode);
    }
}

echo "<xmp>NEW \n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
```

i wonder why it was not working... now it works .

Comment: Actually... If I have alot of empty <opponent/> it only takes one at the time... How does I make it take all the empty ones at once?

Comment: what you mean it takes one at the time???? it looks of all opponent tags in the provided xml

Comment: If you add another <game> with an empty <opponent> it will only remove the first?

Comment: it should remove all the game node which has empty opponent ... did you try with multiple game node with empty opponent child??

Comment: If I do this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
<game id="1">
    <opponent>Michael</opponent>
    <oppid>1</oppid>
</game>
<game id="2">
    <opponent>Trish</opponent>
    <oppid>55</oppid>
</game>
<game id="3">
    <opponent/>
    <oppid>24</oppid>
</game>
<game id="4">
    <opponent>Betty</opponent>
    <oppid>12</oppid>
</game>
<game id="5">
    <opponent/>
    <oppid>24</oppid>
</game>
</data> it only removes the first game with empty opponent?

Comment: i made small changes and it should work... let me know if you still have problem

Comment: Thansk Surace. Thaty did the job :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` condition to following:

```
if($node->opponent->nodeValue == '')
```